# React getDerivedStateFromProps not able to access this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle hook in latest react 16.5.2. Why I am not able to access the this object for component? Is there anything I am doing wrong.

```
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = { email: this.props.defaultEmail };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  getDerivedStateFromProps() {
    this.doSomething();
  }

  doSomething = () => {
   //do something here
  }

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add `static` in front of `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `this` to access non-static method. You need to define static method:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
    EmailInput.doSomething();
   // ^^ class name
   //OR,
   // this.doSomething(); // accessible, coz doSomething is now static method
}
static doSomething() {
   //do something here
}
```

You can learn more about static method here in [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

---

Furthermore, we use `this.props`, `this.state` to access props and states respectively in non-static method. But since [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is a static method, we need to access from it's params:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // correct
  console.log(props, state)
 // incorrect
 // console.log(this.props, this.state)
 // `this` can be used only for static methods
 // that are inside the class
}
```

Comment: But how about the case if need to call setState just after some promise function?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting up a promise from within this method. That's not how it's designed to be used.